# Powershell Regex to match between vertical bar ( | )

Tags: regex, powershell

Below is just two lines of string that I am matching too

```
     6  |UDP     |ENABLED   |        |15006  |010.247.060.120  | UDP/IP Communications  | UDP/IP Communications GH1870

10  |Gway    |ONLINE    |        |41794  |127.000.000.001  | DM-MD64x64  | DM-MD64x64
```

Below is the regex I have so far, but it only matches the bottom line

```
(?i)(?<cipid>([\w\.]+))\s*\|\s*(?<ty>\w+)?\s*\|\s*(?<stat>[\w ]+)\s*\|\s*(?<devid>\w+)?\s*\|\s*(?<prt>\d+)\s*\|\s*(?<ip>([\d\.]+))\s*\|\s*(?<mdl>[\w-]+)\s*\|\s*(?<desc>.+)
```

I was wondering if I could have a regular expression that just matches every character between every vertical line, instead of having to explicitly say what is between the vertical lines

Thanks all

Comment: `\|(?:([^\|]*)\|)*`

Comment: `import-csv -headers 'cipid','ty',... -delimiter '|' -path thatfile.txt` ?

Comment: $array = $line.Split("|") ?

Answer (score 2):

This usually works.  `(?:^|(?<=\|))[^|]*?(?=\||$)`

https://regex101.com/r/KMNc47/1

Formatted

```
 (?: ^ | (?<= \| ) )           # BOS or Pipe behind
 [^|]*?                        # Optional non-pipe chars
 (?= \| | $ )                  # Pipe ahead or EOS
```

---

Here it is with whitespace trim and includes a capture group.

`(?:^|(?<=\|))\s*([^|]*?)\s*(?=\||$)`

https://regex101.com/r/KMNc47/2

Formatted

```
 (?: ^ | (?<= \| ) )           # BOS or Pipe behind
 \s*
 ( [^|]*? )                    # (1), Optional non-pipe chars
 \s*
 (?= \| | $ )                  # Pipe ahead or EOS
```

---

Here it is in a Capture Collection configuration.

`(?:(?:^|\|)\s*([^|]*?)\s*(?=\||$))+`

https://regex101.com/r/KMNc47/3

Formatted

```
(?:
   (?: ^ | \| )                 # BOS or Pipe
   \s*
   ( [^|]*? )                   # (1), Optional non-pipe chars
   \s*
   (?= \| | $ )                 # Pipe ahead or EOS
)+
```